# Error upon File->Open, every time, in TextPad

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, samba, group-policy

I have a Windows 7 Professional desktop that I have begun to use, logged in as a network user to a Samba4 AD domain.

Whenever I go to open a file within TextPad (e.g. by choosing Open from the File menu), I get this error:

> \\*SERVERNAME*\Users$\SYSTEM\Desktop refers to a location that is
>   unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a
>   network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or
>   that you are connected to the Internet or your network, and then try
>   again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been
>   moved to a different location.

I thought that maybe I had a policy misconfigured, but when I checked using the steps described [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/230593-group-policy-editor-quickly-view-enabled-policies-windows.html), I had no policies configured anymore after all.  So I guess it's not that.

Where else could I look to try to get rid of this broken reference?

Comment: On a windows domain, the path would normally be `\\server\users\username\desktop` you appear to be using the SYSTEM account. This isn't "normal" as far as I know.

Comment: @Yorik, yes, that's part of the curiosity here.  I am logged in as a normal user on the domain, not as SYSTEM, which I don't even think is possible.  So where could Windows be getting this string from?

Comment: I don't personally know of any way to unintentionally run an arbitrary program from the GUI under the SYSTEM account. Perhaps the users on the domain are misconfirugered to all point to the system account user directory.

Comment: @Yorik, this is the only account that seems to be exhibiting this problem.  Either way, the question is, where would said misconfiguration be stored?  Also I don't think it's running an arbitrary program, I think it's more like trying to include a folder among the favourites or something like that.

Comment: I am suggesting that the program itself is running under SYSTEM so the %userprofile% points to the SYSTEM user profile rather than the logged-in user. Is this one program doing this, or all programs which have a file>open dialog?

Comment: also if you start>run>cmd and type `echo %userprofile%`, does it show the user's profile path or SYSTEM?

Comment: @Yorik it seems to late, because now it's working, but the user profile pointed to the correct location just now.  Regarding the program, though, I'm pretty sure it wasn't limited to that program, but that was the main one I would use File->Open in.  But now it doesn't happen there or anywhere else.  Weird.

Comment: @Yaris, another restart and the problem is back.  Ran your echo, it shows the user's profile path, not SYSTEM.  Also, I couldn't get it to do it in other programs, only TextPad, whose settings do not reference SYSTEM anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several WU's later, I came up with a different solution, which worked: create the path it's complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a Windows Update in the queue that did something about this.  After a restart, this problem disappeared entirely.

Update: Oddly, after the May 12 Windows Update and another restart, this problem came back again as before.